# mongodb deep update - mongoose .id() causing performance issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongoose level collection schema

```
{
    sublevel: [{
        "deeplevel": [{

        }],
        "deeplevel2": [{

        }],
    }]
}
```

//routes.js

```
dlDoc = { "dl1": "dl1" };
db.levels.update({ _id: ObjectId(levelId), "sublevel._id": ObjectId(sublevelId) }, { $push: { "sublevel.$.deeplevel1": dlDoc } }, function (err, updatedDoc) {
    if (updatedDoc) {
        res.json({ "status": 1 });
        res.end();
        //calling external apis to update more
        result = externalApiResult();
        db.levels.findById(level._id, 'sublevel._id sublevel.deeplevel1', function (err, levelFound) {
            levelFound.sublevel.id(sublevelId).deeplevel.id(dlDoc._id)['result'] = result;
            levelFound.save(function (err, savedDoc) {

            });
        })

    }
});
```

I need to create and update the level collection's deeplevel1. in my case, the deeplevel1 will be inserted more than 2000 sub docs per day. when i want to update using mongoose .id(deepLevelId) function it is causing me performance issues in the server. is there any way to find the position of deeplevel document inserted once i update the level collection?. so that i can use the position in the update query. And please tell me a best way to update my deeplevel subdocuments without causing performance issues and works fast. thanks in advance.

db.collection.findOne() will be like this.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("563b35d1f07cc9d80a26436b"),
"name":"name",
sublevel:[{
  "_id" : ObjectId("569bede3c717b670097519c7"),
  "name" : "name",
  "deeplevel2" : [{
      "_id" : ObjectId("569c559329cc880c18989349"),
      "logTime" : new Date("1/18/2016 03:30:48"),
      "areaId" : ObjectId("568a6129de552e7dba98d547"),
    }, {
      "_id" : ObjectId("569c561929cc880c18989354"),
      "logTime" : new Date("1/18/2016 03:30:48"),
      "areaId" : ObjectId("568a6129de552e7dba98d547"),
    }, {
      "_id" : ObjectId("569c5945626ffb680e4512e9"),
      "logTime" : new Date("1/18/2016 03:30:48"),
      "areaId" : ObjectId("568a6129de552e7dba98d547"),
    }, {
      "_id" : ObjectId("569c594d626ffb680e4512eb"),
      "logTime" : new Date("1/18/2016 03:30:48"),
      "areaId" : ObjectId("568a6129de552e7dba98d547"),
    }
  ]
}]
}
```

Comment: can you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115088/mongodb-set-to-update-or-push-array-element

Comment: I am sorry. i did not mention the correct schema. i need to update a particular document of "deepLevel's" array. How to find position of a deepLevel doc using _id and update it

Comment: Read through the link I pasted..  I think they did discuss about this as well.

Comment: can you please help me why this code is not working as expected.    db.collection.update({"_id": ObjectId("563b35d1f07cc9d80a26436b"), "sublevel._id": ObjectId("563b35d1f07cc9d80a26436c"), "sublevel.deeplevel2._id": ObjectId("565eef6cc7fd9b93ddff09f3"), }, {"$set": {"sublevel.0.deeplevel2.$.comment":"newcomment123"}})

Comment: it is inserting a new subdocument under deeplevel2 instead of updating a deeplevel2 subdocument

Comment: sure, can you paste me a sample document of collection. db.collection.findOne(); ?

Comment: sorry for the delay. i added the code. if you help me, it will be useful for my project. still i could not find what is the issue.