# MongoDB: $push and $addToSet don't work at all

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am a beginner in mongoDB, and I want to use it for a project with NodeJS.
Everything was fine until I had to update some documents in my collection.

So basically, I have a document that is a list of things, and I want to update it by adding something to the list. So I am trying to use the Update method, but I really struggle with the $addToSet and $push (I mean by that that they just don't work).
I think my syntax is correct, because if I do a $set, it works just fine, like that:

```
collection.update(
    { "keyboard.name":"k1" },

    { 
        $set: {
            keys: {
                "myFirstKeyname": {"mySecondKeyname": "myValue"}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
)
```

but if I just replace $set by $addToSet or $push, it doesn't do anything to the database, but I don't have an error either...

I read a lot of things here and there, and I saw that a lot of people had this problem, but I couldn't find a solution.

My guess is that the problem comes from the fact that I try to update a nested field, but I am not sure.

So I tried to do something like that:

```
$addToSet: {
    keys: {
        [myFirstKeyname]: {"mySecondKeyname": "myValue"}
    }
}
```

And I also tried to build my query in javascript like that:

```
toInsert = JSON.parse(obj); // obj comes from the parameters of my function
let keyName = Object.keys(toInsert)[0];
let fieldValue = toInsert[keyName];

let update = { $addToSet: { "keys": {} } }

update['$addToSet']['keys'][keyName] = toInsert[keyName];
update = JSON.stringify(update)
```

which returns this:

```
{ "$addToSet": { "keys": { "myKeyName": {"value": "myValue", "type": "key"} } } }
```

And it works if I replace the $addToSet by a $set.

I also tried the dot notation, but it was not working either, and I can't really use it in my case because I would like a dynamic key name for the new value I insert.
I also tried to copy and paste the example provided in the mongoDB docs, but it didn't work...

Sooo... What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have a sample that works?
Could that come from somewhere else that my code?

Edit: in fact, I was trying to update a sub collection, which is different to an array. That is why $addToSet was not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - $set to update or push Array element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115088/mongodb-set-to-update-or-push-array-element)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally found what the error was!

I just didn't read too carefully the docs, because it says that $addToSet only work with an array.
I was trying to update a subcollection...

So to update a subcollection, you need to use $set. And if you need to update a specific field that has a variable key name, you can build the query with Javascript, like this:

```
let update = {};
update['yourSubCollection.' + yourVariableFieldName] = youValue;
```

and then just do:

```
collection.update(
    yourQuery,
    { 
        $set: update
    },
    [yourOptions]
)
```

Hope this helps!